# KVM and external multiple external IPs

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I want to have KVM with several VMs on it. I have several external IPs connected via one interface. As I understand I cannot use bridging if I want to have each VM with external IP.

Am I wrong? Is there any solution except iptables routing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the VMs to have external IPs, you *should* be using bridged interfaces.